# The interrogative form of “Nous nous tenons bien”

Tags: verbes-pronominaux, interrogative

How is the related question built?

**Tenons-nous bien ?**

or

**Tenons-nous nous bien ?**

or

**Nous tenons-nous bien ?**

Similarly, for “Vous vous mariez”, is the correct answer

**Mariez-vous ?**

or

**Mariez-vous vous ?**

or

**Vous mariez-vous ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that the subject and object pronouns are identical makes the sentences sound a little strange, but doesn't affect the construction.

> Te tiens-tu bien ?
> Nous tenons-nous bien ?
>
> Te maries-tu ?
> Vous mariez-vous ?

“*<s>Tenons-nous nous bien</s>” and “*<s>Mariez-vous vous</s>” are not grammatically correct.

“*Tenons-nous bien !*” and “*Mariez-vous !*” are sentences in the imperative mood (which has no subject).

Comment: Or rather, in which the subject is implied

Answer (score 2):

**Il y a 3 formes interrogatives possibles.**

**La construction la plus élégante: Avec inversion**, celle qui peut présenter le plus de difficultés pour placer les pronoms: pronom réfléchi COD - verbe - pronom sujet

> Nous tenons-nous bien ?
>
> Vous mariez-vous ?

La construction introduite par **est-ce que + forme affirmative + ?**:

> Est-ce que nous nous tenons bien ?
>
> Est-ce que vous vous mariez ?

La construction, un peu plus parlée, **forme affirmative + ?**:

> Nous nous tenons bien ?
>
> Vous vous mariez ?

Answer (score 0):

The third forms are correct French.